# Android text (from speech) interpretation using grammar (w/o using a recognizer)

Tags: android, speech-recognition, grammar, speech, cmusphinx

I use Google Speech Recognizer for Android that I do **not** want to replace.
It produces text, which I want to interpret using my own grammar.

I've checked some tools (like sphinx), but all of them seem to require using their recognizer in order to decode text, but I don't want to use **their** recognizer.

Do you know some tool that can process a given text using a grammar? Or perhaps how can i use sphinx w/o their recognizer?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "process a given text using a grammar"? CMU Sphinx is a speech recognition library, not NLP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammars are equivalent to finite deterministic automata parsing and those are equivalent to [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). So instead of external frameworks you can use Java's regular expressions for parsing the text:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

If you want named regexps you can consider

https://code.google.com/p/named-regexp/

If you want more complex parsing with semantics and intent extraction which goes beyond automata capabilities, you can find corresponding packages in [opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org)

If you want to recognize grammars, you can try CMUSphinx, it's significantly more accurate on constrained recognition.